# How to save information in two files using same serialize method in MFC

Tags: mfc

I am trying to save the information in 2 files after clicking on a button as shown in below, but it is creating file 2 with size as 0KB.Both files are getting created but file1 is having content but file2 is not having content it is of 0kB size.Please let me know what mistake I am doing and also let me know if there is better procedure to store information in two files using serialize method in MFC:

```
   void CMFCserializedemoDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
    {
        // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
        UpdateData(TRUE);
        CEmployee employee;
        CFile file;
        file.Open(L"EmployeeInfo.hse", CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);
        CArchive ar(&file, CArchive::store);
        employee.empID = m_EmployeeId;
        employee.empName = m_EmployeeName;
        employee.age = m_EmployeeAge;
        employee.Serialize(ar);
        ar.Close();
        CFile file2;
        file2.Open(L"EmployeeInfo1.hse", CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);
        CArchive ar1(&file, CArchive::store);
        employee.empID = m_EmployeeId;
        employee.empName = m_EmployeeName;
        employee.age = m_EmployeeAge;
        employee.Serialize(ar1);
        ar1.Close();
    }
    void CEmployee::Serialize(CArchive& ar) {
        CObject::Serialize(ar);

        if (ar.IsStoring())
            ar << empID << empName << age;
        else
            ar >> empID >> empName >> age;
    }
//
class CEmployee : public CObject
{
public:
    int empID;
    CString empName;
    int age;
    CEmployee(void);
    ~CEmployee(void);
private:

public:
    void Serialize(CArchive& ar);
    DECLARE_SERIAL(CEmployee);
};
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `file2.Open(...` and look if the file `EmployeeInfo.hse` has been created when the breakpoint is hit. Then [edit] the questino and tell us what happens..

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Both files are getting created but file1 is having content but file2 is not having content it is of 0kB size.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong in your code. Stepping into the MFC code might help to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: Please suggest me some procedure how can i write info in two file using one serialize method in mfc. please suggest any method.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `CEmployee`

Comment: //
class CEmployee : public CObject
{
public:
 int empID;
 CString empName;
 int age;
 CEmployee(void);
 ~CEmployee(void);
private:

public:
 void Serialize(CArchive& ar);
 DECLARE_SERIAL(CEmployee);
};

Comment: You passing the wrong file into the second archive. See my answer.

Comment: If you enclose both blocks starting with CFile and ending with .Close() with curly braces and compile  you'll see the problem @andrew already pointed - you should pass file2 to ar1.

Comment: A better approach would be to use pass pointer of the class to CEmployee constructor where it can set the values of variables from the parent class. That way there is no duplicate lines like you have setting the values for both files.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
CFile file2;
file2.Open(L"EmployeeInfo1.hse", CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);
CArchive ar1(&file, CArchive::store);
```

Notice that you are passing the address of `file` and not `file2` into the `ar1` variable. This should be:

```
CArchive ar1(&file2, CArchive::store);
```

That is the reason.